# How to refactor standard methods calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

Need idea how to refactor the code:

```
attr_accessor :product
attr_reader :name, :mark

def name=(value)
  super unless product.present?
end

def mark=(value)
  super unless product.present?
end

... and a whole bunch of method of sorts.
```

The idea is simple - to deny assigning values if a product is already set. But the code above isn't DRY at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
attr_accessor :product
attr_reader :name, :mark

["name", "mark"].each do |method|
 define_method("#{method}=") do |value|
  super(value) unless product.present?
 end
end
```

Comment: Well, I've got a RuntimeError:
implicit argument passing of super from method defined by define_method() is not supported. Specify all arguments explicitly.
To make test pass I've changed it to:

super(value) unless product.present?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I made that change to my answer for others who might refer to this

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method such as `attr_*` to handle this. This is done by reopening the `Class` class and defining the following method.

```
def attr_validator(*args)

  #We simply iterate through each passed in argument...
  args.each do |arg|

    # Create an attr_reader
    self.class_eval("
      def #{arg};
        @#{arg};
      end
    ")

    # Here we hardcode "product" since this every attribute
    # checks itself against this object
    self.class_eval("
      def #{arg}=(val);
        super unless product.present?;
      end
    ")                      

  end
end
```

This way, we get rid of the redundancy of appending attributes to the pre-processor method (in my case, `attr_validator`) and also a different array for metaprogramming purposes.

This can be used thus...

```
attr_accessor :product
attr_validator :name, :mark, :price, :stock # ...and so on
```